# Joomla 3.2 autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, autocomplete, joomla3.2

I want an autocomplete field in my page, and my code is right, but it doesn't work. When I used Joomla 2.5 then it worked but I had to change to Joomla 3.2 and it isn't working now. I use these js files:

```
$doc->addScript(JURI::root().'media/com_szakdolgozat/js/jquery.min.1.4.2.js');
$doc->addScript(JURI::root().'media/com_szakdolgozat/js/typeahead.bundle.js');
$doc->addScript(JURI::root().'media/com_szakdolgozat/js/jquery-ui.min.1.8.1.js');
```

There is a problem with jquery 1.8.1, because I get error under Joomla 3.2:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined** -->  jquery-ui.min.1.8.1.js:10

Which version shall be right for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla 3.x comes packed with jQuery by default, therefore you do not need to import your own copy of it. The following code will import it in **noConflict** mode if it doesn't already detect it:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

I think the issue you're having mentioned in your question is that you have 2 instances of jQuery being loaded and therefore it causes conflicts.

Joomla 3.x also has jQueryUI packed with it. So your final code will look like this:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JHtml::_('jquery.ui');
JHtml::_('script', 'media/com_szakdolgozat/js/typeahead.bundle.js');
```